# how to change the visibility/opacity of another html element by hovering over another html element using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to make the "close button" be visible to the user as they hover in another element, to indicate that they could delete that element. Here's the attempted jquery function:

```
$("[id^='titleNotes'],[id^='contentNotes']").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).closest("button").find("[id^='deleteNotes']").css("visibility", "visible");
    });
```

as you can see, I attempted to find the nearest button with an id which has a name that starts with "deleteNotes" (because all of my "deleteNotes" id name ends with a unique number).

here's the css:

```
button[id^=deleteNotes] {
    visibility: hidden;
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    right: -5px;
    top: 15px;
}
button[id^=deleteNotes]:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

and here's the code where the close button is used:

```
<div class="grid-padding-all" id="<?php echo $note_id; ?>">
    <button type="button" id="deleteNotes<?php echo $note_id; ?>" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <textarea name="note_title" id="titleNotes<?php echo $note_id; ?>" class="note_display_title" readonly="" title="created on <?php echo $date_created; ?>. Note type: <?php echo $note_type; ?>"><?php echo $note_title; ?></textarea>
    <textarea name="note_record" id="contentNotes<?php echo $note_id; ?>" class="note_display_record" readonly="" title="created on <?php echo $date_created; ?>. Note type: <?php echo $note_type; ?>"><?php echo $note_record; ?></textarea>
</div>
```

I might be approaching it wrong using css or have created a wrong jquery for searching the closest close button. is there a much better approach out there in displaying the close button everytime I hover my mouse on the textboxes?

sample jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x5no0vh3/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.closest() searches through the parents of the given element. Button is not a parent here.
Try:
`$("[id^='titleNotes'],[id^='contentNotes']").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).closest(".grid-padding-all").children("[id^='deleteNotes']").css("visibility", "visible");
 });`

Comment: this works terrific. thanks :) now I have a minor problem. i need to revert the visibility back to hidden once I leave the hover state. i wonder how could that be?

Comment: `$("[id^='titleNotes'],[id^='contentNotes']").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).closest(".grid-padding-all").children("[id^='deleteNotes']").css("visibility", "visible");
 }).mouseleave(function(){$(this).closest(".grid-padding-all").children("[id^='deleteNotes']").css("visibility", "hidden");});`

Answer (score 0):

you are attempting to find the element in button

try using this

```
$(this).parent().find("[id^='deleteNotes']").css("visibility", "visible");});
```

Comment: this works terrific. thanks :)

now I have a minor problem. i need to revert the visibility back to hidden once I leave the hover state. i wonder how could that be?